# RAM required for kernel update

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, apt, out-of-memory

I have a small debian VM.  For normal application usage, I only need about 1.5GB ram max (typical approx 500MB).
However, I when I do an apt upgrade, sometimes I will trigger the OOM when there is a kernel update.  I think it is on the rebuilding of the initramfs but perhaps other steps as well.

Therefore, what is the minimum amount of ram needed to perform a kernel update via apt?

Comment: I doubt we can give an absolute value, have you tried running this without a GUI open? Or adding some swap?

Comment: no gui install, I just installed some swap.  Not looking for an absolute value

Comment: I have no idea what is happening, but if it's really a kernel update, you can do that manually before you do the rest of the update. See if that also leads to the OOM.